# IE8 does not clone elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

IE has confused me. I have two lists. One container.

The first list is filled with `<option>` of the branches. Mother branches.

The second list is empty for now.

The container which is a `<div>` is then filled with `<option>` of all child branches of all mother branches. There are many of them. But this container is hidden.

I have written jQuery code, to select the set of matched elements which are the child of the selected mother branch, and clone them into the child branch list.

check this **fiddle** to see it in action : http://jsfiddle.net/mostafatalebi/6WQ9x/

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#branches').on('change', function(){
        var branch = $(this).val();
        var subholder = $('#subbranch-holder');             
        // $('#sub').empty();                                           
        $('#sub').html("<option value='false'>انتخاب زیر شاخه ها</option>");
        // console.log(subholder.children('option').length);
        subholder.children('option').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('id') == 'par'+branch) {                            
                var tempItem = $(this);
                // $("#sub").append('this is : ');
                $(this).clone().appendTo("#sub");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It works every where except IE.

the INTERESTING POINT IS THAT when I put the following line instead of the `clone()`, IE works:

```
$("#sub").append('IE is the worst browser');
```

It seems IE is in problem with `$(this)` and `clone()`

Older versions of jQuery have been tested. All have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer to this problem.

It seems `<option>` behaves quite differently than the other.

What I did was that, I used `<input>` tag instead of the  tag, filled the "value" attribute with ID of child-branch, and filled the "id" attribute with parent_id of the child-branch preceded with "par" string, and eventually used "name" attribute to fill it with title of the child branch. Correspondingly I retrieved them in jQuery and it worked.

All of this efforts have been taken to fit it into IE8 whose usage is very limited, but still the customer insisted.